# Using TortoiseSVN with repository sitting on external server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

This should be a seemingly simple task, but dont know too much about the setup of tortoiseSVN.

So I have an external server that I access using RDP - I want to place my MVC project in a folder and then be able to checkin and checkout changes I do on my local. There will be more than 1 Developer that will need to access this folder, so that we know we both have any changes we both have made(i.e we both have the latest versions so no need for manual merging)

How do I do this setup ? I am sure I need to provide the username and password somewhere to allow TortoiseSVN to checkout the project that sits on this server ?

What Ive done:

1. Installed TortoiseSVN on the server and right clicked on the folder I want to use and clicked "Create Repository"
2. I created a folder on my local and tried to checkout the folder on the server by using the following url:
3. I opened up port 3960 and 3980 on the external server(Based on a post I read)

   svn://server.co.za/repositoryname and it seemed to try connect, but took long and then provided this error:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I was not aware of this, but you need to install a Subversion on the server first. Here are the steps:

1. Download a subversion, I used VisualSVN. I saw a lot of people recommending it, and so do I, it is actually quite easy to use! Go to the following link and click on the red download button: https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/ - Then install it on your server and follow this youtube guide, which helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6Obh2UuUw4
2. Download TortoiseSVN and install it on your local machine where you do your development: https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

That simply put, is what I did. The Youtube guide should help you to achieve what you are looking for.

Hope this helps someone.